# Distributed build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have one test execution job in Jenkins. That job consist of many test cases so to reduce build time I want it to execute in distributed manner. Suppose job has 100 test cases and if i trigger the job build then slave 1 should execute 50 test cases and slave 2 should execute remaining 50 test cases. How to achieve this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) you can easily distribute job tasks between any any number of agents with help of [`parallel`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) section. Example `Jenkinsfile` doing what you wanted might look like that:

```java
pipeline {
    agent none 
    stages {
        stage('Tests') {
            parallel {
                stage('Tests1') {
                    agent { label 'slave1' }
                    steps {
                        echo "tests part 1"
                    }
                }
                stage('Tests2') {
                    agent { label 'slave2' }
                    steps {
                        echo "tests part 2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more sophisticated scenarios you could add [`matrix`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix) section combined with labelled agents.

Let's assume you have some Jenkins slaves labelled `'test-runner'` and you split your tests in 10 parts. With `matrix` you could run up to 10 tasks at once (limited by number of agents):

```java
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Distribute Tests') {
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'PART'
                        values '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Tests') {
                        agent { label 'test-runner' }
                        steps {
                            echo "tests part ${PART}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Tupteq for your quick response